# Google Forms Flow not working as expected

Tags: google-workspace, google-forms

I have a Google Form with 4 sections and it is setup like this:

Section 1 - One multiple choice question

- Yes (Go to section 2)
- No (Go to section 3)

[image]

Section 2 - A few questions

- After finished go to section 4

[image]

Section 3 - A few different questions

- After finished go to section 4

[image]

Section 4

- Complete the form

[image]

In section 1, if I choose No, the form works as expected an goes to section 3 then section 4 and finishes.  However, if I choose Yes in section 1, it goes to section 2, then section 3 then section 4.  It should be skipping section 3.

At the end of section 2 I have the setting as 'After section 2 Go to section 4' but it keep going to section 3.

I have tried both the old and new versions of forms with no luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it should work.
Here is a [form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/18QDB1SRjKDJYOl_QuEpcDGIo9kpq1tLtjmSylQ1x1yU/viewform) created using the New Forms with the settings you posted.
It works as expected:

Just make sure after each section you continue to next section.

- After section 1 Continue to next section
- After section 2 Continue to next section
- After section 3 Continue to next section

---

**EDIT**

After you posting the screenshots my answer could be:

Just make sure Section both sections 2 & 3 point to Section 4.

- After section 1 Continue to next section
- After section 2 Continue to Section 4
- After section 3 Continue to Section 4

Actually it should work both ways, unless there is something else interfering (like a script).

Comment: I think I'll have to recreate mine from scratch because something must be stuck.  Thanks for the post.

Comment: My flow is correct.  I've triple checked it and had a few other people have a look as well.

Comment: Could you share the form so I could have a look? You could make a copy and erase any sensitive data.

Comment: I am not the owner of the file so I can't share to public, I will update my question with some screen shots

Comment: After you posting the screenshots I updated my answer.

Comment: @tyelford Did you get to try the form I created?  Did it finally work out for you?

Comment: I ended up having to recreate the form.  I copied everything exact as it was from the first form and it was working fine.  Some glitch with that form I guess.

Comment: You haven't accepted my answer and I thought there was something wrong with it. I guess not. Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score -2):

There is an option at the bottom of the section in the Google Form. So if you don't choose that it will continue the next section. Below is the option we have to choose at the end of each section:

[image]